# JSLint : 'numeral' was used before defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

My code runs fine, but I have no idea why JSLint (running on Brackets text editor) keeps telling me: *'numeral' was used before it was defined*

I am using Numeral.js to display numbers with commas. Below is the code I am using.

```
$("input[name='service']").click(function () {
    var a = parseInt($("#product-one input:checked").val(), 10),
        b = parseInt($("#product-two input:checked").val(), 10),
        c = parseInt($("#product-three input:checked").val(), 10),
        total = numeral(a + b + c).format('0,0');
    $(".number").text('$' + total);
});
```

I ran into similar problems before when I started learning JQuery a few months ago. It kept telling me *$* and *alert* were undefined, but after some digging around I figured I had to put this on top of my JS file:

/*global $, JQuery*/

and

/*jslint devel: true*/

Is there a similar fix for this?

Comment: where is numeral defined? in the same file as the code you've shown? no? then how is jslint supposed to know?

Comment: @JaromandaX They are using numeral.js so I guess it's imported from the module.

Comment: Yes, I know that ... but jslint isn't psychic :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - Not yet. Crockford is working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same problem you had before; you are correct. Simply add `numeral` to the list of global variables you want your linter to recognize, and it should leave them alone:

```
/* global $, JQuery, numeral */
```